# Cannot abort interrupted rebase

Tags: mercurial

My repository is stuck in an apparent interrupted rebase: If I try a new commit, I get this message:

```
abort: rebase in progress
(use 'hg rebase --continue' or 'hg rebase --abort')
```

But `hg rebase --abort` fails with the message

```
abort: unknown revision '<hex id>'!
```

I even tried `hg rebase --continue`, but got the same error. `hg verify` thinks everything is ok. Is there a way I can get the repository unwedged, or do I have to throw it out and make a fresh clone? (Fortunately I was able to simply `hg clone` the broken repo and leave the problems behind. But I'd still like to know a better way out).

I have no idea how the repository got in this state; I might have done something that caused it months ago, I might not. I just got back to the repo and ran into this. (I do use rebase on occasion, and have never had problems). I looked for a backup bundle, but don't see one.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `hg verify`.  Something's wrong according to that last message.

Comment: Do you use MQ? I'm wondering if you were in the middle of rebasing a patch queue, and now the patch queue has disappeared... I'm wondering if that's why trying to abort or continue the rebase gives an "unknown revision" error. Pure speculation, of course.

Comment: I've used mq, but I don't think it was involved here. I remember seeing the problem back then, being unable to resolve it, and having do drop it and move on to other stuff. But I'm more concerned with the general question of repository unwedging; if this this can pass `hg verify`, isn't there something else that checks more carefully?

Comment: PS. In the meantime I got back to work by cloning the broken repo (no problem) and correcting the upstream path by hand. But I kept the broken version so I can test suggestions for how to repair it.

Answer (score 2):

`hg debugcheckstate` specifically examines "the correctness of the dirstate."  I'm uncertain whether its checks are a subset of those performed by `hg verify`, but it couldn't hurt.

In situations similar to this one, you may be able to proceed with `hg debugsetparents tip; hg up -C .` (optionally replacing `tip` with a changeset ID) and then use `hg strip` to throw out any partially-rebased commits you don't want to keep.  This basically overrides the usual `hg update` system and sets the working directory's parent to `tip` manually.  The `hg up -C` then cleans up the working directory.

It is possible you will lose data by doing this; you should have a backup (e.g. on Bitbucket) from which you can `hg pull` any lost changesets.  In a worst-case scenario, a new clone may be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kevin. I'll go look for my wedged repository (I no longer remember just where I stashed it) and try it out.

Comment: Re backing up: a recursive copy of the entire project directory, including the .hg subdirectory, is best and simplest in this case. It's too late to `hg clone` (since the repo is wedged), and an earlier clone would be missing some committed or uncommitted work.